# Map UNIX "nobody" and "nogroup" to Win32 Accounts/SIDs?

Tags: unix, winapi, posix, sid

How can we map UNIX "nobody"/"nogroup" to Win32 SIDs/accounts? Cygwin has entries for "nobody" in /etc/passwd and "nogroup" in /etc/group, but these accounts have SIDs returned by /usr/bin/getent passwd and /usr/bin/getent group which LookupAccountSidA() does not recognise.

So what is the correct Win32 solution, without relying on Cygwin?

Comment: Your question is incoherent and lacks sufficient detail and context. If you aren't executing in a Cygwin environment what does it mean to map the Unix concept of the `nobody`/`nogroup` group IDs to a Windows equivalent? Does Windows even have something like Unix groups?

Comment: My question is not incoherent. Cygwin is a POSIX emulation layer on top of Win32, but adds UNIX accounts on top of the Windows accounts. In this case it adds SIDs for "nobody" and "nogroup" for which Windows does not have accounts for (that's why LookupAccountSidA() is not working), so this is not a solution.

So, is there a mapping for UNIX "nobody" and "nogroup" to Window SIDs, which does not involve Cygwin, and is resolveable by LookupAccountSidA()?